# How do I choose the python-framework where to install packages with pip?

Tags: macos, python, pip

I have two python-frameworks installed on my Mac OS X 10.6.8: one standard (`/usr/bin/python`) and now I installed 3.3.

I have already figured out that `pip` is installing things into `site-packages` but at the standard-python, now I need it to do this not for python 2.6.1, but for the new 3.3.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is the path of the 3.1 version, i.e. how is its binary called and where is it on your system?

Comment: Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/

Comment: binary is called python3

Comment: Is `pip` in that 3.3's `bin` folder? If so, you could symlink it to `/usr/bin/pip3`, for example.

Comment: well i found it under the python2.6 folder, so i think i have to install it for python3.3-

Comment: See: [How to install pip with Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: Did you mean Python 3.3 in your original question, or 3.1? You really don't want to be doing a fresh install of 3.1 unless you have a very good reason...

Comment: I am sorry, i meant 3.3 . I solved the thing, but i am also using django and this one of the worst choices u can make. right now i am trying to deinstall django through pip and it is throwing exception. don't bother ..

Comment: thx for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the site-package by invoking `pip` with the `python` where you want the modules in.

```
/usr/bin/python -V
-> Python 2.7.9

/usr/bin/python -m pip install this
-> /path/to/Python/2.7/site-packages/this

/usr/local/bin/python3 -V
-> Python 3.3

/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install this
-> /path/to/Python/3.3/site-packages/this
```

If you want to know, which modules are inside your `side-packages` type

```
/path/to/python -m pip list
```